# How to ECHO string inside the array?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, echo

Here is my code on loading the data into the array by using a loop : 
and i want to echo the data out in words late but i receive an error "Notice: Array to string conversion in..."

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 4 ; $i++)  { 
    $options[] = $row3= mysqli_fetch_array($result3);                
}
echo $options[0];
```

Comment: it is array not a string check it with: `var_dump($options[0]);`

Comment: Why would you need the extra $row3 variable? Instead you should use `$options[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);` and if you want to output the first row value of the first record, it should read `echo $options[0][0];`

Comment: this is what i got :array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["idoptions"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(16) "image/image2.jpg" ["options"]=> string(16) "image/image2.jpg" }

Comment: seems like yo are taking the long way around this, can you post your sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all about:

```
$options[] = $row3= mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
```

mysqli_fetch_array($result3) returns an array. So $row3 is an array and $options[] is an array. So when you do print `$options[0]` you are printing an array.

User `print_r($options[0]);` to print the complete array.

Also you could use:

```
echo $options[0]['idoptions'], $options[0]['options'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_array` returns an array, so `$row3` and `$options[n]` are arrays, hence the "Notice: Array to string conversion..."

`$options[0][0]` would be the first element of the first row in the result set,

Answer (score 0):

just write

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 4 ; $i++)  { 
    $options[i] = $row3= mysqli_fetch_array($result3);   
   }
print_r($options)
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_result_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row or `NULL` if there are no more rows in resultset.

Every index of your `$options` array contains an array. So if you want to `echo` a particular index of this array, then first take `print_r($options);` to see the sub-indices of each index of `$options`.